# Change HTML page after x second

Tags: javascript, splash-screen

I develop a mobile app using phonegap.
I have two file html (splash.html , index.html).
So, I'd like that the app start with splash.html and after X seconds, change page to index.html.

How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
function delay(){
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href='index.html'
},5000);}
```

Comment: What if user wants to skip the splash screen by clicking on it.

Comment: usually the splashscreen is used to cover up the main page until all the data were loaded. so the user is not allowed to skip

Answer (score 5):

With JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = 'index.html';
}, 2000);
```

Without JavaScript:

```
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=index.html">
</head>
```

Comment: @SamuelLiew: That is not a JavaScript issue, it is a PhoneGap issue: `<content src="splash.html"/>` in the app's `config.xml `.

Comment: What means by : content=2 ?

Comment: @partho: Not `content=2`, see where the quotes are. `<meta http-equiv>` "fakes" HTTP headers. One such header is `Refresh`. The content we want to give this header is `2; url=index.html`: in two seconds, reload the page from `index.html`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice well. And now I got that.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform this task only using HTML redirection meta tag like following :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://yoursite.com/">
```

The fact that I didn't precised any file after your site absolute URL is because the default file are loaded, and `index.html` is a default file.

Answer (score 0):

```
function delay(){
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href='index.html'
},5000);}
```